# Setting state in OnMouseOver event returns TypeError: Cannot read property - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Although finding loads of posts about this error, I can't seem to fix it in my specific case.

I have a set of items and I am trying to color these items (the div's) when you hover over them. The coloring happens when the `state` of these items (`reserved`) is false and the `starting state` is set to true. 
So when an item is clicked (`MouseDown` event) I am setting the `starting condition` (state to true), then when I mouse over the next item, and the start condition is true and the item being moused over has it's `reserved state property` set to false, it should change it's background color and so on for the next items which are being moused over.

This is now being done as follows:

**Defining the Items and start condition in the (initial) state:**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        items: [
            {
                name: 'test1',
                key: '#test1',
                reserved: false,
            },
            {
                name: 'test2',
                key: '#test2',     
                reserved: false, 
            },
            {
                name: 'test3',
                key: '#test3',
                reserved: false,  
            },
            {
                name: 'test4',
                key: '#test4',
                reserved: false,  
            },
            {
                name: 'test5',
                key: '#test5',
                reserved: false,   
            },
        ],

        startCondition: false

    }
}
```

**Render the List item:**

```
render() {

  return (    
    <FocusZone>
      <List
        items={this.state.items}
        onRenderCell={this._onRenderCell}
      />
    </FocusZone>
  );
}
```

In the `_onRenderCell` event I am rendering each cell (item div) and setting the `onMouseDown`, `onMouseUp` and `onMouseOver` events, I also check the `reserved` state of the item here so that when the item becomes `reserved = true` it gets an extra `css class` which contains the different background color:

```
_onRenderCell = (item, index) => {

    let className = 'ms-ListGridExample-label';

    if (item.reserved === true) {
        className += ' reservation-creating';
    }

    return (
      <div
        className="ms-ListGridExample-tile"
        data-is-focusable={false}
        style={{
          width: 100 / this._columnCount + '%',
          height: this._rowHeight * 1.5,
          float: 'left'
        }}
      >
        <div className="ms-ListGridExample-sizer">
          <div className="msListGridExample-padder">

            <span className={className}
                 onMouseOver={() => this._onMouseOver(item.name)} 
                 onMouseUp={() => this._onMouseUp(item)} 
                 onMouseDown={() => this._onMouseDown(item.name)} 
            >
                {item.name}

            </span>

            <span className="urenboeken-bottom"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
};
```

So when an item is clicked (`MouseDown` event) it sets the starting condition to true and also set it to `reserved` to give it the extra `css class` (with it's different `background color`):

```
_onMouseDown(name){
    if (this.state.startCondition === false){
        this.setState({startCondition: true});

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            items: prevState.items.map(item => {

                if (item.name === name) {
                    if (item.reserved === true)
                    {
                        item.reserved = false
                    }
                    else if (item.reserved === false)
                    {
                        item.reserved = true
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.reserved = false
                    }
                }
                return item;
            })
        }))
    }
}
```

After the `MouseDown` event has been fired and the `Start Condition` is being set, the moving will be tracked with the `MouseOver` event and setting the `reserved state` to true:

```
 _onMouseOver(name) {
    if (this.state.startCondition === true) {

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            items: prevState.items.map(item => {
                if (item.reserved === false) {
                    if (item.name === name) {
                        item.reserved = true
                    }

                    return item;
                }
            })
        })) 
    }
}
```

At this point, the `_OnRenderCell` is fired again and returns me the error:

```
MyClass.js:265 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reserved' of undefined
    at MyClass._this._onRenderCell
```

which is the following part in the `_onRenderCell` function:

```
if (item.reserved === true)
```

I am probably doing something obvious wrong but I cant seem to point out what it is.

P.s. the `onMouseUp` event reset the `starting condition` to false.

**UPDATE**

On request of @M.Fazio, who suspects something is going wrong with the `items={this.state.items}` part in the `List` rendering, I added a log to display what is inside the items just before rendering:

```
render() {
    let tItems; 

    tItems = this.state.items.map(item => { 
        console.log('Item name = ' + item.name + ' item reserved = ' + item.reserved);
    });  

  return (  

    <FocusZone>
      <List
        items={this.state.items}
        onRenderCell={this._onRenderCell}
      />
    </FocusZone>
  );
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Some things to point out:**

- The `OnRenderCell` gets called for every item in the array (which is logical).
- The `List` rendering seem to happen three times, why?
- When doing the process (`onMouseDown` + `onMouseOver` event) the following happens (error now actually already happens on the added logging):
  [image]

**Solution**

@M.Fazio found the solution. In the end it was a small glitch (though so hard to find for myself). 
The `return item;` in the `_onMouseOver` event was inside the `if condition`, moving it outside the `if condition` made it working!

Comment: The issue seems to be near `if (item.reserved === true) {` in _onRenderCell. Are you sure item is defined in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ListComponent`, when you're calling the `onRenderCell` prop, you have to pass your parameters. Did you ?
Maybe past the code of your `ListComponent` so we can help you ?

Comment: The List component is the default `List` component of `Fabric React` found here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/list  On inspecting the List componenet the OnRenderCell looks like: `onRenderCell: function (item, index, containsFocus) { return React.createElement("div", null, (item && item.name) || ''); },`

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from `this.state.items`. What's inside just before you render the `List` ?

Comment: I added the result to the main post in the UPDATE section (below). Some interesting thing happening.

Comment: Actually I think I found the problem. In your `_onMouseOver` you have to move the `return` outside the `if (item.reserved === false) {` condition.
Tell me if it works

Comment: That was it! So simple, yet so hard to find (for me). Thank you a lot! I have updated the solution in my post.